# JSON parsing error when trying to use Face API

Tags: c#, json, face-api

I'm trying to send photo from Imgur via URL adress to Microsoft Face API and get ID of face from Json response but when I try to run the code, I always get JSON parsing error. I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

I tried to make this request via Postman and everything is working fine there but in c# it just won't work.

Can you help me please?

```
    static void TryFunction()
    {
        string host = "https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect?returnFaceId=true";
        string subscriptionKey = "...";

        body = new System.Object[] { new { url = @"https://i.imgur.com/... .png" } };
        var requestBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body);

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);
            request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
            request.RequestUri = new Uri(host);
            request.Content = new StringContent(requestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
            var jsonResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonResponse);
            Console.WriteLine(jsonResponse);
        }
    }
```

> {"error": {"code":"BadArgument", "message":"JSON parsing error."}}

The C# request body looks like this:

```
[{"url":"https://i.imgur.com/... .png"}]
```

Whereas the Postman request body looks like this:

```
{ "url": "https://i.imgur.com/... .png" }
```

Comment: What's different between your C# request and your Postman request? You can use a tool like Telerik's Fiddler to find out. The only thing that stands out to me (not knowing the face API) is: are you meant to be passing an array, or a single object?

Comment: Diference is between body request.
This is what it look like:
`[{"url":"https://i.imgur.com/... .png"}]`
This is how it should look like: 
`{
    "url": "https://i.imgur.com/... .png"
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, you are expecting a single object, but generating an array. This is down to the following line of code:

```
body = new System.Object[] { new { url = @"https://i.imgur.com/... .png" } };
```

This creates an array with a single item in it. What you actually want is just a single item:

```
body = new { url = @"https://i.imgur.com/... .png" };
```

Note that `[ ]` in JSON is an array, and `{ }` in JSON is an object.